# Git hooks, pulling from git hub

Tags: git, deployment, githooks

Is it possible to push to GitHub from your computer then have a git hook that automatically pulls from GitHub on the server without having to ssh into the server?

Or am I misunderstanding git hooks?

Comment: Github it's not a git. Nor git is github. So, what hooks you exactly ask about?

Comment: Thanks Marcin for letting us all know that. Git Hooks bro, Git hub is a remote origin... Unless it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are [called **webhooks**](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) on GitHub, but they need a listener, on your server, which will listen to the JSON payload sent by GitHub.
Do not mix them with [Git Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) (local to your repo)

See [Configuring your server](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/configuring/) to define your listener.

Comment: ah okay, so I'll see about these web hooks. Thanks V. I'll try this out.